# Quotient group of descending central series of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Define $\gamma_k(G)$ to be the $k$th term of the descending central series of $G$ defined by $\gamma_1(G)=G$ and $\gamma_{k+1}(G)=[\gamma_k(G),G]$ with $k\geq 1$.

What can we say about relations (if any) between the following two groups?

1. $A=\gamma_k(H)/\gamma_{k+1}(H)$;
2. $B=(H\bigcap\gamma_k(G))/(H\bigcap\gamma_{k+1}(G))$.

My observation is that generally $A\neq B$. Is it true that $B$ is always a factor group of $A$?

Comment: $B$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A$ by the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt, the $2$nd Isomorphism Theorem says that $(SN)/N$ is isomorphic to $S/S\bigcap N$; why does this imply your conclusion?

Comment: I think you should be able to figure that out yourself!